# Get data from db Mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ok, I now introduce the problem, I have 3 tables `Company`, `CompanyName`, `Project`. In `Company` i have many companies id and projects id, in  `CompanyName` names of all companies, in `Project` have names of all project.

If you not understand i will give example,

- `Company`: 1, 3; 5, 7; . . .
- `CompanyName`: 1, FirstName; 2 Secondname; 3 Thirdname; . . .
- `Project`: 1, Firstproject; 2, SecondProject; . . .

Result must be: Company name - Project name

- FirstName - Third project
- FifthName - Seventh project

But I don't know hot to get data from db like in the example `Company name - Project name`

I never do SQL query with 3 tables.

My bad you not understand the question ;(

**See:**

- Table `Company` have 2 rows (3 but we need only 2): `CompanyID`  and
  `ProjectId`
- Table `CompanyName` have 2 rows: `Id` and `Name`
- Table `Project` have 2 rows `Id` and `Name`

In Table `Company` are only numbers for example `CompanyID=3`  and `ProjectId=100`

And I dont know, WHEN I HAVE `CompanyID=3`  and `ProjectId=100` get data from `CompanyName` and  `Project` and answer must be `THEcompany3 = TheProject100`.

Comment: Can you do a query with two tables? Or just don't know the syntax for JOIN at all?

Comment: I cant do, but I dont dont know good algoritm, what do with data select all 3 rows or something else ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this might work:

```
SELECT 
    companyName, projectName, companyID
FROM
    company c 
INNER JOIN 
    companyName cn ON c.companyID=cn.companyID
INNER JOIN
    project p ON c.companyID=p.companyID
```

Editted with new query

```
SELECT 
    cn.name, p.name
FROM
    company c
INNER JOIN 
    companyName cn ON c.companyID=companyName.ID
INNER JOIN
    project p ON c.companyID=project.ID
```

Is that what you're after?

Comment: companyName, projectName is now ROW, this is 3 tables companyName, projectName, company.

Comment: I've added companyID to the SELECT statement - is that what you mean?

Comment: Please look at my first post I edit it, maybe now it will be easier understandable for you   ;)

Comment: And how is this different from my initial answer ?

Comment: @Razvan - aside from having the right field names, I believe it's identical to both our previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select cn.companyname, p.projectname 
FROM company c, projects p, companyname cn 
WHERE c.id = p.id AND c.id = cn.id
```